# How to set up a local MySQL database for dev purposes in Sierra?

Tags: macos, mysql

I am developing a PHP web application where all data is to be stored in a MySQL database but unfortunately have no server on which to upload it to and even if I did I will be working offline quite a bit.  My question is how to set up a database for free using a normal install process (I don't have sudo privileges in the terminal but can type in administrator password to install or download) that doesn't use up a ton of storage. To be clear, I do not need a massive database in which to store tons of data, I will be clearing it and resetting it to test various features all the time.

Comment: use their docker container

Answer (score 1):

What about one of the memory databases available ??

[HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org/) (HSQLDB)

[H2 Database Engine](http://www.h2database.com/)

Comment: Could I use it with Netbeans?  I'm just getting used to this whole database thing...

Comment: Why not ?? Here is how h2 is been set up in Netbeans: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34034872/connecting-to-h2-from-netbeans - and it is the same procedure with hsqldb

Answer (score 0):

MySQL offers pre-built macOS installers. You can find them [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/).

Comment: Those are huge production type downloads upwards of 1GB and I am looking for something simple.  All I need is something for PHP's mysqli to interact with until I am closer to being finished!